# Netezza pick value from next record

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a Netezza table like this:

```
ID     START_DATE
1      01-Jan-2000
1      31-Jan-2000
2      01-Jan-2000
2      15-Jan-2000
2      31-Jan-2000
```

I want to create a column END_DATE by picking the date from the next record for the same ID. For the 'last' record for an ID, I want to put '31DEC9999'

```
ID     START_DATE     END_DATE
1      01-Jan-2000     31-Jan-2000  
1      31-Jan-2000     31-DEC-9999
2      01-Jan-2000     15-Jan-2000
2      15-Jan-2000     31-Jan-2000
2      31-Jan-2000     31-DEC-9999
```

How can I do this in Netezza SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netezza supports the `lead()` analytic function.  So:

```
select t.*,
       lead(start_date) over (partition by id order by start_date) as end_date
from t;
```

If you really want an arcane date instead of `NULL`, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(lead(start_date) over (partition by id order by start_date),
                date '9999-DEC-31') as end_date
from t;
```

EDIT:

As Scott suggests in a comment, the `coalesce()` is not necessary:

```
select t.*,
       lead(start_date, 1, date '9999-DEC-31'
           ) over (partition by id order by start_date) as end_date
from t;
```

Comment: What an elegant solution!Thank you

Comment: Netezza also supports  offset and default for lag/lead, so you can use "lead(start_date,0,'9999-DEC-31')  over ..." if you didn't want to use coalesce for the out of bound case.

Comment: @ScottMcG . . . That is a very good suggestion.  The third argument to `lag()`/`lead()` is ANSI standard, and I regularly forget about it.